How does Swagger UI create default request body JSON?
I have a Spring Boot application with configured OpenAPI and able to show the Swagger UI. I see all the endpoints with all the supported HTTP verbs in that UI and many of those endpoints have example request data for e.g. POST as well. But not all, some of the endpoints have a default value of the following:

That "string" is wrong, the request body needs to be a special User-DTO and in the section of Schemas at the bottom of the UI that DTO is properly shown with all its fields etc. So the UI seems to be aware of that DTO, but for some reason can't create a default request for it.
It needs to look at something, but I don't know what. It's not only @Schema and stuff, because some of the endpoints with example request data don't use those annotations at all, but still the UI renders example requests.
It's at well not only the mapping itself, because for historical reasons most of my controllers extend some generic stuff handling POST for all controllers and different entities. But for some controllers and entities the UI does render example request data and for some it doesn't, even though all of those share the same generic implementation.
So how does the UI create those example bodies?
Thanks!

Try to use:
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Description", content = {  @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = YourClass.class), mediaType = "application/json") }),

